# How to change the logic for the last element while mapping an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say there exists an array of keys:

```
[ "link1", "link2", "link3" ]
```

and there is a JSON object called links that is in the following format:

```
{
  "link1": "https://google.com/",
  "link2": "https://facebook.com/",
  "link3": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
}
```

I'm currently working on a React project to practice my JS, and in this project, I needa figure out how to print out these as anchor tags, separated by commas besides for the last element.  The desired output for the example would be something along these lines:

```
link1, link2, and link3
```

Except they would be anchor tags correlating to the proper links.  How would you recommend I approach this problem?

Edit:
Currently this is my approach:

```
return links.map((key) => {
  return (
    <span><a href={this.props.content.links[key]} key={key}>{key}</a></span>
  )
})
```

So far, it's returning them like Link1Link2Link3 (as expected).  To clarify my question. I'm just looking for a pointer on if there's any methods or whatnot that would make it possible to detect if the key that I'm on is the last key in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mapping an array in JS, it is possible to simultaneously access the index. You simply need to pass a function `(key, index) => ...` instead of only asking for the key. If the current index is equal to the length of the array minus 1 (because indices start from 0), you are on the last element of the array.

Here's an example:

```
const arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
const result = arr.map((x, i) => i === arr.length - 1 ? "Hello" + x : x)

console.log(result) // => ["foo", "bar", "Hello baz"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the index parameter of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
return links.map((key, index, arr) => {
  console.log(arr.length - 1 === index) // true if last index
})
```

Comment: You should also show the original array. Often times when you create a utility function it's best to make it generic, especially when you might not have a pointer to the original array to closure too:
    return links.map((key, index, array) => { console.log( index == array.length); } // last index ... }

Comment: @RobertMennell Thanks for your comment. But is it really needed in this scenario?

Comment: Definitely not in this case, and IMO there's no reason to make this method generic. But since you decided to update the code, I'd also update the description to include the oft-forgotten third parameter :)

Comment: It will be when they wants to use that map in a different element in react and now they can without having to worry about it being modified

Comment: If you're abstracting out this "mapLastElement" function, you're going to be taking an `arr` parameter anyway, which you can close over: `const mapLast = (f, arr) => arr.map((v, i) => i === arr.length - 1 ? f(v) : v)`. Having the `arr` passed to you on every iteration is unnecessary.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin it's new term here for me. But I'm not able to understand this currying function over here.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I don't think so; the point of the function parameter to `map` is so you can call it directly on the array--that *is* the `mapLastElement` function. If you abstracted out the call on the array itself (to accept an array) you'd have to pass *two* functions, one for every element but the last, and one for the last, which seems even *more* awful.

Comment: @RobertMennell The thing about something like "do this on every element except for the last when you should do this" is that abstracting it out is *very* specialized. At that point the only reason to abstract it out is so you can test it on a single element (which is valuable, I suppose, but you could also just call it on single-element lists). *shrug*

Comment: @DaveNewton The snippet above (`const mapLast = ...`) only accepts two parameters, a function for transforming the last element and a container in which to transform the last element, not "*two* functions, one for ...". This isn't terribly unconventional either, the implementation of `map` for all functors looks like `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css:

(I used scss, but can be with css too)

```
  span {
    &::after {
      content: ', ';
      display: inline-block;
    }
    &:nth-last-child(2)::after {
      content: ' and ';
    }
    &:nth-last-child(1)::after {
      content: '';
    }
  }
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/maniator/oqrw2ukh/

Comment: Ah, my mistake... I din't realize. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

JS has the built in function, `array.join()`. It loops through the array, creating a single string of all items, separated by the character used as an argument.

If the arguments are left blank ( `.join()` ), it defaults to a single comma; any string put in the argument will be used (e.g. `.join('-')` or `.join('apple')`.

See my snippet below for it in action:

```js
var linksObj = {
  "link1": "https://google.com/",
  "link2": "https://facebook.com/",
  "link3": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
}

var linksAnchor = []; // Prepare empty array

for (let item in linksObj) {
  // Poplate array with the span and anchors, set to the original object
  linksAnchor.push('<span><a href="' + linksObj[item] + '">' + item + '</a></span>');
}

// Empty (default) join, uses a single comma
document.getElementById('navlistjoin').innerHTML = linksAnchor.join();

// Join using space, comma, then another space
document.getElementById('navlistjoinscs').innerHTML = linksAnchor.join(' , ');

// Join using a dash
document.getElementById('navlistjoindash').innerHTML = linksAnchor.join('-');

// Join using the string 'apple'
document.getElementById('navlistjoinapple').innerHTML = linksAnchor.join('apple');
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF0000;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h4>.join()</h4>
<nav id="navlistjoin"></nav>
<h4>.join(' , ')</h4>
<nav id="navlistjoinscs"></nav>
<h4>.join('-')</h4>
<nav id="navlistjoindash"></nav>
<h4>.join('apple')</h4>
<nav id="navlistjoinapple"></nav>
```